# ¿Cómo puedo pasar la fecha del cliente al servidor usando un shortcode de Wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Tengo programado un shortcode que genera contenido en el servidor basado en un calendario.

Básicamente el código del servidor toma un intervalo semanal partiendo del domingo de la semana en curso hasta el domingo de la semana siguiente, pero la fecha de partida se toma en el servidor, no en el cliente. Eso hace que, mientras para unos clientes es domingo en un determinado tiempo, para otros clientes no, porque se usa siempre la zona horaria/fecha del servidor.

Pienso que una solución óptima sería pasarle la fecha en el shortcode, tomándola del cliente.

¿Es esto posible? ¿De qué modo?

He revisado la [documentación](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) y buscado en la red y no encuentro nada al respecto.

Mi shortcode es simple:

```
[liturgia-semanal]
```

Y me gustaría poder pasar algo así:

```
[liturgia-semanal fecha="LA FECHA TOMADA DESDE EL CLIENTE"]
```

Este es mi código en el servidor, el cual funciona, pero, como dije, tomando la fecha del servidor:

Registro el shortcode:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[liturgia-semanal]' );
```

Y esta es la función:

```
function liturgia_semanal(  ) {
    $service_account_file = '***.json';
    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . $service_account_file);
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->setApplicationName('MY APP');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    $calendarId = 'c_*****@group.calendar.google.com';
    /* Aquí usar fecha pasada desde el cliente para crear los intervalos*/
    $mDate = new DateTime('next Sunday');
    $to=$mDate->format('d')."-".$mDate->format('m')."-".$mDate->format('Y');
    $endDate=$mDate->format('c');
    $iniDate=$mDate->modify('-1 week')->format('c');
    $from=$mDate->format('d')."-".$mDate->format('m')."-".$mDate->format('Y');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: La plantilla se procesa del lado del servidor, por lo que tienes dos opciones: 1. Obtener la diferencia horaria en el cliente y enviarla por AJAX. 2. Usar la librería [GeoIp](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.geoip.php) que no siempre está instalada en el servidor, aunque está la librería del desarrollador [Maxmind GeoIp](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/), tiene opción gratuita, que es la que usa PHP. ¡Ah!, también podrías guardar una cookie en el servidor y leerla con PHP.

Comment: Perdón por el error, la sugerencia es crear la cookie en el cliente y leerla (en una siguiente carga) en el servidor, no muy viable, por cierto.